# Noise in beginning of alsa application

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I have ALSA driver for capture device which works fine with VLC. when I try to capture and render using own application having some issues. Issue is:When I start play, it has some noise in beginning and audio is discontinuous in between. Discontinuous means, some audio frame are getting dropped in between. It looks like cut cut sound for sine wave and it continuous to play. I have tried snd_pcm_drop and snd_pcm_drain but no use.

For rendering audio I'm using aplay.c file as a reference. However, using play.c code I'm getting noise in beginning, to cross check this I have dumped application buffer and then played using aplay utility. Content in application buffer is fine. I have also confirmed with FFPlay application. FFPlay also plays with out noise. aplay [reference](https://github.com/bear24rw/alsa-utils/blob/master/aplay/aplay.c) link , and my audio render is similar to reference link.

Why is there noise while playing audio in beginning?

Comment: See Arch wiki, it covers good issues which may help you https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting

Comment: @ jesuismasoud, thank you for sharing this info. I will try it.